# how to perform In-game mouse movements for FPS games using java (or maybe writing drivers for the task?)

Tags: java, kotlin

#### Hi there, a little background for what I am going for

My service will enable users to use their android device to play PC games by streaming a running instance of their game from their pc to the mobile device. This involves being able to stream and control the pc using the android. I am trying to create two separate applications -

- Android app - This side will have the controls and all that.
- Windows java based app - This will be responsible for performing controls for the device from the data it receives from the android device.

---

Now I know some of you would say `java.awt.robot` might just work (as I found in other stackoverflow questions). So, I'll leave two pieces of code down below and you can see what they do inside a game and why they aren't usable.

##### THESE CODES ARE KOTLIN CODES. FOR THOSE WHO DON'T KNOW, KOTLIN AND JAVA ARE INTEROPERABLE AND SO, KOTLIN CAN USE JAVA LIBRARIES. KOTLIN CODE CONVERTS TO JAVA BYTE CODE.

### Using delta (or change in position) -

```
val robot = Robot()
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    for (i in 0..200) {
        Thread.sleep(20)
        testMouseDelta(100, 0)//moves mouse to right by 100px
    }
}

fun testMouseDelta(dx: Int, dy: Int) {
    robot.mouseMove(
        MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().location.x + dx,
        MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().location.y + dy
    )
}
```

[image: sample gif]

The game acts as if it has reached the right edge of the screen and won't rotate right anymore.(it should keep rotating for 20ms * 200 = 4000ms)

### Using hardcoded values -

```
val robot = Robot()
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    for (i in 0..10000 step 50) {
        Thread.sleep(20)
        robot.mouseMove(
            i,
            MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().location.y
        )//moves mouse to right by 50px
    }
}
```

[image: sample gif]

What I found was that the game kinda looped on itself. You might notice it at the end of the gif. the rotation glitches to a completely different angle.

---

#### Now that you guys have a little bit of a background of what I am trying to achieve, let's discuss the issue I am encountering.

Up until now, I was using `java.awt.robot` to perform all my actions and it was working fine until I realized that it cannot be used for mouse controls in-game. I looked around multiple places for about a week just to find a simple code that would just work (didn't find it). What I found was that I might need to make it such that the game feels as if its receiving data directly from a hardware mouse and this is because games interact with the mouse controls differently and just using the above mentioned library isn't a solution. So, now I think I only have two options.

1. Wait around in hope of a piece of java code that would solve this issue instantly.
2. Write a mouse driver and figure out how the heck I would interact with it in java.

I don't have any clue for how to work with either of these two options. I have no idea about driver coding. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `The game acts as if it has reached the right edge of the screen` - i am not really sure what that means. But the logic for moving mouse pointer to the right eventually **will** make the pointer reach the right edge of the screen and continue trying to move more to the right, even though it's not possible. I don't know how this game is supposed to behave when screen edge is reached during rotation, but most games i have played do exactly this kind of strange and sudden change in view angle when this happens. Considering that you don't handle this case, it looks like expected behaviour to me.

Comment: @Chaosfire It is unexpected behavior. You would want the camera to keep rotating for the entire loop interval instead of not being able to rotate after a limit. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause is the fact that you continue moving the pointer right, even when the edge is reached. I got 2 ideas, which might help.

1. Check the position of the pointer in the loop. If it has reached the end of the screen (`x` coordinate equals width of the screen), release all buttons (if any are clicked), move pointer maximum to the left, click all previous buttons (if any), continue loop.
2. Keep both screens in sync. This would require some calculations, but the general idea is get width of the mobile screen and calculate the movement as percentage of the screen, then move mouse pointer in computer with the same percentage of its' scrren. Example:

```
mobileScreen = 500px
mobileMovement = 50px
percent = 10%
pcScreen = 2000px
pcMovement = 2000px * 10% = 200px
```

Tbh, i am not sure either will fix issue, but i think it's worth a try. You can get the screen dimensions like so:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```